# Selenium - using WebDriver interface as type

Tags: java, selenium

Less of a concrete question but still valid I think.

Selenium tutorial presents an example of obtaining a driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

However, this prevents us from using browser-specific drivers' methods. In my case it was setProxy(). Hence, I used:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setProxy("someproxy", 6666);
```

The question is: why would I limit myself to using methods only from the WebDriver interface, when I know which driver I want to use?

Comment: what if today you used driver "a" along with method "foo" and tomorrow you changes the driver to "b" but it doesnt have the method "foo" implemented?

Comment: In my case, I have to use the setProxy() method so an implementation of WebDriver without it would be useless for me. Is there another way to set a proxy in Selenium?

Comment: I guess using desiredcapabilites you can achieve this

Comment: This would probably do fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So:

Using the **WebDriver** interface as a type is better because it provides flexibility: different types of WebDrivers (such as FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver etc.) could be required at different times.

Setting a proxy could be done with Proxy and DesiredCapabilities. To cite the [Selenium Tutorial](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy):

```
String PROXY = "localhost:8080";

org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
 .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
 .setSslProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```